# Arduino connection to brainwave analyzing module

Tags: power, pins, electronics, electricity

I want to connect a TGAM module (detecting brainwaves) to an Arduino Uno. I know little of electronics, can someone advise me? To which pin of the Arduino should I connect the TGAM? How to get the right electrical supply from the Arduino to the TGAM? Here is data about the TGAM module: http://www.seeedstudio.com/document/pdf/TGAM%20Datasheet.pdf

The R pin on the TGAM module is providing digital data as an asynchronous serial stream of bytes: http://developer.neurosky.com/docs/doku.php?id=thinkgear_communications_protocol

Answer (score 2):

As per the datasheet you provided, it is quite straight forward.
It can be connected to RX (pin 0) and TX (pin 0) pins of the Arduino Uno.
But, the pins have to be crossed;

Arduino RX (0) <> TGAM T (TX)

Arduino TX (1) <> TGAM R (RX)

Arduino 3.3V <> TGAM + (VCC)

Arduino GND <> TGAM - (GND)

Good luck.